# Entities inheriting Entity.lua variables, but not its methods

Tags: oop, inheritance, lua, game-development, love2d

I am building a game with enemies and players, all of which are set up to have various states for animation and behavior.  The parent class for both is Entity.lua, from which they inherit variables and methods.  However, while both enemies and players are inheriting the variables, for some reason the enemies do not inherit the methods.  So, if I try to call snakey:changeState('search'), for example, it gives me an error message "Attempt to call method 'changeState' (a nil value)".

I have used the same sequence for creating entities in several games in the past and never had this problem.  In fact, if I create the Player in the same way, file and location as the enemies, I receive no error messages.

Here is the code where I create the entities.

```
local snakey
snakey = Snakey {
    platform = platform,
    player1 = self.player1,
    player2 = self.player2,
    stateMachine = StateMachine {
        ['search'] = function() return SnakeySearchState(snakey) end,
        ['chasing'] = function() return SnakeyChasingState(snakey) end,
        ['idle'] = function() return SnakeyIdleState(snakey) end
    }
}
-- snakey:changeState('search')
-- snakey.stateMachine:change('search', params)
table.insert(self.entities, snakey)
```

The two coded out lines are where I noticed the problem.  The first line gives and error and the second does work, but is not satisfactory because it is a work-around.

Here is the code for Entity.lua:  I don't include details of the functions for brevity, but all are working properly for when player calls them.

```
Entity = Class{}

function Entity:init(def)
    -- position
    self.x = def.x
    self.y = def.y
    self.gravity = 6

    -- many more variables
  
end

function Entity:changeState(state, params)
    self.stateMachine:change(state)
end


function Entity:update(dt)
    self.stateMachine:update(dt)
end

function Entity:collides(entity)
    -- do something
end

function Entity:onDamage()
    -- do something
end

function Entity:render()
    - renders sprite
end
```

Player code (in brief)

```
Player = Class{__includes = Entity}

function Player:init(def)
    Entity.init(self, def)
    -- more variables
end

function Player:update(dt)
    Entity.update(self, dt)
end

function Player:render()
    Entity.render(self)
end
```

And perhaps the trouble spot, one one enemy's script

```
Snakey = Class{__includes = Entity}

function Snakey:init(def)
    Entity.init(self, def)
    -- yet more variables
end

function Snakey:update(dt)
    Entity.update(self, dt)
 -- entity behavior (works fine, so omitted)
end

function Snakey:render()
    Entity.render(self)
end
```

Thank you very much for your help.  I'm feeling quite frustrated because this sequence has worked in the past and I would really like to know why it's not calling those Entity methods.

Adding the class library

```
--Copyright (c) 2010-2013 Matthias Richter

local function include_helper(to, from, seen)
    if from == nil then
        return to
    elseif type(from) ~= 'table' then
        return from
    elseif seen[from] then
        return seen[from]
    end

    seen[from] = to
    for k,v in pairs(from) do
        k = include_helper({}, k, seen) -- keys might also be tables
        if to[k] == nil then
            to[k] = include_helper({}, v, seen)
        end
    end
    return to
end

-- deeply copies `other' into `class'. keys in `other' that are already
-- defined in `class' are omitted
local function include(class, other)
    return include_helper(class, other, {})
end

-- returns a deep copy of `other'
local function clone(other)
    return setmetatable(include({}, other), getmetatable(other))
end

local function new(class)
    -- mixins
    class = class or {}  -- class can be nil
    local inc = class.__includes or {}
    if getmetatable(inc) then inc = {inc} end

    for _, other in ipairs(inc) do
        if type(other) == "string" then
            other = _G[other]
        end
        include(class, other)
    end

    -- class implementation
    class.__index = class
    class.init    = class.init    or class[1] or function() end
    class.include = class.include or include
    class.clone   = class.clone   or clone

    -- constructor call
    return setmetatable(class, {__call = function(c, ...)
        local o = setmetatable({}, c)
        o:init(...)
        return o
    end})
end

-- interface for cross class-system compatibility (see https://github.com/bartbes/Class-Commons).
if class_commons ~= false and not common then
    common = {}
    function common.class(name, prototype, parent)
        return new{__includes = {prototype, parent}}
    end
    function common.instance(class, ...)
        return class(...)
    end
end


-- the module
return setmetatable({new = new, include = include, clone = clone},
    {__call = function(_,...) return new(...) end})
```

Comment: `Player` and `Snakey` appear to have the exact same code. We'll need a minimal, reproduceable example to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: The error message is `Attempt to call method 'checkCollision' (a nil value)`, but you did not show us how you define this method.

Comment: How `Class` is implemented?  Probably you have file `Class.lua` in your project.  Show it.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it!  I'll get to work on putting together an MRC, which will take a few hours.  In the meanwhile, here is the class.lua library I'm using.

Comment: Also edited to show that "changeState" is the function that I got the error message from.  All functions (methods) in Entity give that error, but changeState is where I first noticed it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that sequence matters.  In trying to create the minimum reproducible code I could not reproduce the error.  After some searching (and a little frustration), I noticed that in Dependencies.lua I was requiring the enemies BEFORE Entity.lua, but Player.lua was required after.  I would have thought this wouldn't matter, since everything was imported into the program on frame 1 and I was creating entities on something like frame 1000, but alas.  Anyway, problem solved!  Always require parent classes before child classes...  Lesson learned.  :)